# SQL groupings for desired expected report

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

The requested result is:

```
styleNumber colorCode   asset.url
1021A166    600 https://IMAGE , https://IMAGE 1, https://IMAGE 2,https://IMAGE 3,https://IMAGE 4
1021A163    1   https://IMAGE , https://IMAGE 1, https://IMAGE 2,https://IMAGE 3,
```

And I do have database data that is:

```
styleNumber colorID assetURL
1021A163    1   https://images
1021A163    1   https://images1
1021A163    1   https://images2
1021A166    600 https://images
1021A166    600 https://images1
1021A166    600 https://images2
1021A166    600 https://images3
1021A166    600 https://images4
```

May you help me on how to query to get the desired result.

Comment: You want some kind of string aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you searching for:

Your database:

| styleNumber | colorID | assetURL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1021A163 | 1 | https://images |
| 1021A163 | 1 | https://images1 |
| 1021A163 | 1 | https://images2 |
| 1021A163 | 1 | https://images3 |

Your expected result:

| styleNumber | colorID | assetURL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1021A163 | 1 | https://images, https://images1, https://images2, https://images3 |

Then here is the query:

```
SELECT styleNumber, colorId, GROUP_CONCAT(assetURL)
FROM yourtable
group by styleNumber, colorId
```

Comment: How did you know the OP’s database suppprts GROUP_CONCAT?

Comment: Hi Nguyen Van,

Please see below Error Message

Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'GROUP_CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @MervinContawe which sql server are you using?

Comment: Hi Nguyen,

Thank you for your help, i just got the script i need.
.
.

SELECT DISTINCT
      m.styleNumber
    , m.colorId
    , assetURLs = STUFF((
          SELECT ', ' + md.assetURL
          FROM ASICS_Assets md
          WHERE m.styleNumber = md.styleNumber and m.colorId = md.colorID
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM myTable m
ORDER BY 1,2

Answer (score 0):

Since SQL Server 2017, you can use `string_agg()`:

```
select styleNumber, colorCode,
       string_agg(asset_URL, ', ') within group (order by asset_URL)
from t
group by styleNumber, colorCode;
```

In earlier versions you need to use a workaround such as `for xml path`.